# Intermittent error thrown by Flask: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'resp' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask

If this code fails, then there are other code blocks that should in my Flask app. I've tried various ways of fixing this and then out of the blue i got this error again, without changing any code :/ I'm a newbie to python i guess so any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance guys.

````
@flask_app.route('/demo/login', methods=['POST']) 
def login():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        #successful login [DL3.2] 
        if pem.validate_sis_login(request.form['username'],request.form['password']) == True:
        
            #plan expired?
            db = sqlite3.connect(__CORE_DB_PATH__)
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT plan_end_date FROM accounts WHERE username='"+request.form['username']+"'")
            result = cursor.fetchone() 
            db.close()
            plan_end_date = datetime.strptime(str(result[0][:19]),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            
            if datetime.today() < plan_end_date:

                if datetime.today() > plan_end_date:

                    resp = make_response(render_template('account_expired.html'))

                else:

                    resp = make_response(render_template('pmuser_loggedin.html'))
                    resp.set_cookie('sis_login', request.form['username'])
                    resp.set_cookie('sis_pswd', request.form['password'])

                    # GET ORG to find right USER DB: -----------------
                    global __DBUSER__
                    db = sqlite3.connect(__CORE_DB_PATH__)
                    cursor = db.cursor()
                    cursor.execute("SELECT org_abbrev FROM accounts WHERE username='"+request.form['username']+"'")
                    result = cursor.fetchone() 
                    db.close()
                    org = str(result)[1:-2]
                    __DBUSER__ = org
                    
                    resp.set_cookie('__DBUSER__', __DBUSER__)
        
        else:

            resp = make_response(render_template('index_demo.html',message="Username and or password were not recognised, please try again"))
        
    return resp```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `if datetime.today() < plan_end_date:` condition is false there is no way for `resp` variable to get initialized. But you have returned `resp` in return statement. So in that case you are referencing `resp` before assignment. And the error is raised.

To get rid of this error please ensure that `resp` gets initialized in each branch or define it at the top of the function with a `default` value.

Comment: Thanks! My goodness, how on earth did i miss that? lol. Much appreciated! I deleted that line, and now works - the account had expired which is why i suddenly got this error. Thanks for helping me catch this during alpha!

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you use the variable `resp` before you have declared it. In other words, it does not exist. I suspect that the problem is your `if` statement because you write `out of the blue i got this error again, without changing any code`. This probably means that you have entered a branch in the `if` statement that you have not before. Can you please post under which conditions it does fail, and under which it does not?